# RichTextBox with default text

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a `RichTextBox` that I want to display a default (gray color) text "enter text here" before the user writes or when the user deletes his text. The problem is that user can edit the default text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a default value you put and play with the `GotFocus` event.

```
  public Form1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     richTextBox1.Text = "enter text here";
     richTextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
     richTextBox1.GotFocus += new EventHandler(richTextBox1_GotFocus);
     richTextBox1.LostFocus += new EventHandler(richTextBox1_LostFocus);
  }

  void richTextBox1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (richTextBox1.Text.Equals(string.Empty))
     {
        richTextBox1.Text = "enter text here";
        richTextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
     }
  }

  void richTextBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (richTextBox1.Text.Equals("enter text here"))
     {
        richTextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        richTextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
     }
  }
```